# Timeline instances not on first frame

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

It's been a while since I've had to write Actionscript that **really** needs to integrate with the timeline (in this case, controlling a series of frames that must happen in a certain sequence) and I am trying to figure out what to do.

In the first few frames, I have a button "next_1".

At frame 10, I need to have another button "next_2". I really really need this button to not be on frame one (I could possibly just make it invisible, but that's going to create a clickable area that I don't want).

The problem is, anything I don't put on "frame_1" renders as null in my Document class.

Is there any solution to this? I would rather not have to write my script on the timeline if possible (it seems easier in the long run to keep it in a document class)...

Answer (score 1):

Items on the timeline are created on the fly, so if the playhead has not reached frame 10, next_2 is not created.

Easiest Document-class solution:

1. Create an array of frame labels like ["label1", "label2"]
2. Create sectionIndex var and set it to 0
3. Create a next button on its own layer so it is always showing.
4. When the next button is clicked, increment sectionIndex, then gotoAndPlay(myLabels[sectionIndex])

Answer (score 0):

Okay, directly lifted from "Real World Flash Game Development":

```
/**************************************************
* FRAME LABELS *
**************************************************/
private function enumerateFrameLabels():void {
   for each (var label:FrameLabel in currentLabels) {
       addFrameScript(label.frame-1, dispatchFrameEvent);
   }
}

private function dispatchFrameEvent():void {
   dispatchEvent(new Event(currentLabel, true));
}
```

This dispatches an event at each frame label on the timeline.

Then you can just add event listeners for each frame:

```
addEventListener("name_of_my_framelabel", frameHandler);
addEventListener("another_framelabel", frameHandler);
```

And write a switch statement to add event listeners for the buttons when they actually show up on the timeline.

```
private function frameHandler(e:Event):void {
            switch(e.type) {
                case 'screen_2':
                    stop();
                    next_2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click2, false, 0, true)
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Sure, if your buttons are an integral part of the animation and cannot be separated. Still, a simple enterFrame handler and a check of currentFrameLabel would suffice. But then you wouldn't get to use the cool addFrameScript....